# Can't open downloaded games

Tags: games

I downloaded several games from the available free list.  Free cell, Pacman, Frozen -Bubble, etc.  But now can't get them to open.  I get the dropdown asking if I wish to remove or download but there's nowhere to open and play, and they don't show on my launcher bar.  What might I have done wrong, or not done?

Comment: Can you provide more information with screenshots? where you download them, websites or Ubuntu Software Center? And show me your dropdown prompt (some screenshots).

Comment: what's your version of ubuntu? perhaps you should press the super key (normally windows) and type in the name of the game and perhaps that may find it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your have Ubuntu 12.04 and are using Unity, you can access these games by opening the Dash. (You can use the Windows [Superkey] to open the dash)

When the Dash is opened simply type Free Cell , Pacman for Frozen Bubble and respective icon will appear.

You can drag each icon to the launcher if you wish them to appear there for future use. (Hold the mouse on the Icon, drag it to the launcher then release the mouse button)

For more information on how do do this and other options for opening applications please review [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41208/how-to-launch-an-application-in-unity)

Comment: At a guess I think you were trying to open them from the Ubuntu Software Centre