# Installation error Google Drive did not Sync. Run Grive Setup again

Tags: 12.04, grive

I followed this link http://www.thefanclub.co.za/content/how-install-grive-tools-ubuntu-1204-64bit to install grive in my ubuntu 12.04. This link says that this suits 12.04.
But after I finished installation and tried to setup.
After I entered the authentication code, it gave me an error.

Installation error

Google Drive did not Sync.

Run Grive Setup again

Does anyone know what problem it may be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Google Drive client available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available) and install the up-to-date version of grive in Ubuntu 12.04 from the PPA by following the instructions in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/320333#320333).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 is NOT officially supported because of dependency issues and besides
 [THIS PROJECT IS NO LONGER SUPPORTED DUE TO GOOGLE DRIVE API CHANGES](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/content/how-install-grive-tools-ubuntu-1204-64bit) .
Here is the installation instruction of "overGrive", the new Google Drive client.

Step 1:  [Download the latest version of overGrive (.deb) here](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/all/modules/pubdlcnt/pubdlcnt.php?file=https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/default/files/public/overgrive/overgrive_3.1.2_all.deb&nid=168)

Step 2: Launch overGrive from [launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41208/how-to-launch-an-application-in-unity)

Step 3: A window will appear - click on <kbd>Connect account</kbd>.
Then a  browser window will open for you to `sign in` to your Google account.

Step 4: At the end you will get a **code**.
Copy that code and paste it into the overGrive window at **Account** entry box and click <kbd>validate</kbd>.

Step 5: After setting your preferences (like location, etc.) click <kbd>Start Sync</kbd>.

Reference [here](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive/installation-instructions-ubuntu)

Comment: @Zizhao please accept it as answer if it solved your Q...I tested the answer in my system--working =)