# How to mount Google Drive, without grive?

Tags: 14.04, mount, google-drive

Since grive no longer works with new Google API, how do I mount Google Drive?

Comment: [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) is a tiny open source command-line program to pull or push Google Drive files. [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://launchpad.net/~alessandro-strada/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) is a FUSE filesystem backed by Google Drive, written in OCaml. It lets you mount your Google Drive on Linux, but it is missing working offline. [How to install google-drive-ocamlfuse](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/320333#320333)

Comment: @karel: I'll flag your comment as "not a comment" **;-)**. This is an answer.

Comment: tried google-drive-ocamlfuse and it didn't work for me, it's an ancient approach. I'd rather stick with web version then this. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thanks for giving your feedback. There may not be a free grive replacement that is  ready to be accepted into the Ubuntu Software Center in time for the 15.10 release.

Comment: I think grive is no longer useful to anyone since it fails to do it's essential function sync or push files, and it's due to Google's changes.  So the only fully functional and featurific option at this point is the web? =(

Comment: @Joe: I can confirm that google-drive-ocamlfuse works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you, it is an alternate to Grive tools.

Installation of "**overGrive**", the new Google Drive client:

Step 1:  [Download the latest version of overGrive (.deb) here.](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/all/modules/pubdlcnt/pubdlcnt.php?file=https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/default/files/public/overgrive/overgrive_3.1.2_all.deb&nid=168)

Step 2: Launch OneGrive from [launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41208/how-to-launch-an-application-in-unity).

Step 3: A window will appear - click on <kbd>Connect account</kbd>.
Then a  browser window will open for you to `sign in` to your Google account.

Step 4: At the end you will get a **code**.
Copy this code and paste it in the overGrive window at **Account** entry box and click <kbd>validate</kbd>.

Step 5: After setting your preferences (like location, etc.) click <kbd>Start Sync</kbd>.

Reference [here](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive/installation-instructions-ubuntu)

Comment: Be careful with this. I just realized that it uses 1-7 GB of my Internet data for upload every day, even if I don't change anything and my Google Drive has only 3.3 GBs of data. It sucked more than 100GB for a month.