# Failed to install Grive tools on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ppa, grive

I was trying to install `Grive tools` via the PPA, but in the last step I got the error message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y grive-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grive-tools
```

I had cut and paste the preceeding commands as mentioned. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: which ppa you used?  Grive Tools PPA does not officially support Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 is NOT officially supported because of dependency issues and besides
 [THIS PROJECT IS NO LONGER SUPPORTED DUE TO GOOGLE DRIVE API CHANGES](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/content/how-install-grive-tools-ubuntu-1204-64bit) .
Here is the installation instruction of "overGrive", the new Google Drive client.

Step 1:  [Download the latest version of overGrive (.deb) here.](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/all/modules/pubdlcnt/pubdlcnt.php?file=https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/default/files/public/overgrive/overgrive_3.1.2_all.deb&nid=168)

Step 2: Launch overGrive from [launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41208/how-to-launch-an-application-in-unity)

Step 3: A window will appear - click on <kbd>Connect account</kbd>.
Then a  browser window will open for you to `sign in` to your Google account.

Step 4: At the end you will get a **code**.
Copy that **code** and paste it into the overGrive window at **Account** entry box and click <kbd>validate</kbd>.

Step 5: After setting your preferences (like location, etc.) click <kbd>Start Sync</kbd>.

Reference [here](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive/installation-instructions-ubuntu)

Comment: Commenting so I can remember this is here.  Thanks Ravan!  =)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ravan. I have installed it and it seems to be working Ok, accept that I have it only for 14 days!

Comment: @RamanChawla please accept it as answer so future reader identifies it as corect answer for your Q

Answer (score 0):

`Grive-tools` is available for Ubuntu 12.10, 13.04, 13.10, 14.04, 14.10, 15.04. Debian and Mint should also work with minor changes to the instructions. it will not support 12.04 or earlier version. you can try manual installation [installation](http://www.lbreda.com/grive/installation).

Comment: now better ...;=)